# Testing ActionMailer's receive method (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, actionmailer

There is good documentation out there on testing ActionMailer send methods which deliver mail.

But I'm unable to figure out how to test a `receive` method that is used to parse incoming mail.

I want to do something like this:

```
require 'test_helper'
class ReceiverTest < ActionMailer::TestCase

  test "parse incoming mail" do
    email = TMail::Mail.parse(File.open("test/fixtures/emails/example1.txt",'r').read)
    assert_difference "ProcessedMail.count" do
      Receiver.receive email
    end
  end
end
```

But I get the following error on the line which calls Receiver.receive

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `index' for #<TMail::Mail:0x102c4a6f0>
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/tmail-1.2.7.1/lib/tmail/stringio.rb:128:in `gets'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/tmail-1.2.7.1/lib/tmail/mail.rb:392:in `parse_header'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/tmail-1.2.7.1/lib/tmail/mail.rb:139:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/tmail-1.2.7.1/lib/tmail/stringio.rb:43:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/tmail-1.2.7.1/lib/tmail/port.rb:340:in `ropen'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/tmail-1.2.7.1/lib/tmail/mail.rb:138:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/tmail-1.2.7.1/lib/tmail/mail.rb:123:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/tmail-1.2.7.1/lib/tmail/mail.rb:123:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionmailer-2.3.4/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:417:in `receive'
```

Tmail is parsing the test file I have correctly.  So that's not it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  Was passing a TMail object into the "receive" method.  It should take just a plain old string instead (does the parsing into a TMail object on it's own).